# Changing text of div element after user input

Tags: javascript, text, input

I want to change the text of the div "result" when a person writes something in the text box and make it the text the user wrote. is anyone pro/smart/knowledgeable enough to help me? I m new to java script so please help me. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script>
function updateText(text){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =text;
}
}</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="text">
Write to change:<input id="slide" type="text" value=""
onchange="updateText(this.value);" />


</div>
<div id="result" style="height:40px;width:40px;border:1px solid #999"></div>
<br/>
</body>

</html>
```

i would also like to know how to insert text which the user wrote into a prompt box into that element of the page.

Comment: you got a syntax error in your js (remove the extra `}`)

Comment: @user2313853 If you have two questions you should probably not combine them in one like this. For your code example, I recommended closing, as it will unlikely help others here on SO. Your other question ('how to insert...'), hidden at the end, will be ignored because of that combining, if this question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

You code is absolutely fine except the fact that you used one extra '}' in your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>    
    <script>
    function updateText(text){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =text;
    }
    </script>    
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div id="text">
    Write to change:<input id="slide" type="text" value=""
    onchange="updateText(this.value);" />
    </div>
    <div id="result" style="height:40px;width:40px;border:1px solid #999"></div>
    <br/>
    </body>    
    </html>
```

However in the browser screen, you can see the output only when you leave the control away from Text-field.
Try clicking somewhere else in the browser after giving some input.

Comment: Josh already found the syntax error, you should IMHO give him credit for that in your answer, although repeating that here to make your answer complete OK (especially for people to lazy to read comments).

Comment: @Anthon Agreed that the extra '{' was pointed out earlier, but since questioner is new to JavaScript, I assumed she might be expecting output without revoking the control away from text field(onChange won't trigger). so approached to just elaborate a bit more. :)

Comment: I agree that your answer adds value, I would just have started answering with 'As Josh already pointed out...'. (Josh' comment was originally an answer and moved by one of the moderators, on my flag)